# Problems making soup: BeautifulSoup not opening entire page source, stopping at /html

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm pretty new to scraping and would appreciate your help.

I am trying to open the following url using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2
import csv
import re

amicales = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.journal-officiel.gouv.fr/association/index.php?ACTION=Rechercher&HI_PAGE=1&HI_COMPTEUR=0&original_method=get&WHAT=&JTH_ID=014000%2F014040&JAN_BD_CP=&JRE_ID=%CEle-de-France%2FParis&JAN_LIEU_DECL=&JTY_ID=&JTY_WALDEC=&JTY_SIREN=&JPA_D_D=&JPA_D_F=&rechercher.x=36&rechercher.y=7&rechercher=Rechercher")
soup = BeautifulSoup(amicales)
```

I want to scrape results from a search query. The problem is, every result that I am interested in ends with /html.
I believe this is forcing beautifulsoup to stop reading the source code after the first search result, such that the remaining 20 or so results are ignored.

Here, for example, only the result "NATION INITIATIVE ET OU MACHROU3 WATTAN" is included:

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

Can anyone help me to open the whole page, and not just everything before the first /html tag?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a very valid question, and the solution is not obvious to someone not well-versed in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear, that website is thoroughly broken. You can only have one `</html>` tag per page. If you look at the source, you see that there is only one `<html>` tag (as opposed to 50 `</html>` tags.

One workaround would be to first remove all the `</html>` tags before passing it to BeautifulSoup.

```
page = page.replace("</html>", "")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, I just saw your message. I should have thought of that, it's a great idea. I'll let you know if I get it to work. Thanks!